# Orgmode custom agenda view - remove unecessary info and align tags

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I can't seem to find a way to get the "default" (t) agenda view so I can edit it an comment out stuff. Basically what I have now is:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with `N r': (0)[ALL]
 My super long file name:TODO Get milk           :groceries:
 My super long file name:TODO Fix Conky   :fixes:
```

But what I want is:

```
 TODO Get milk           :groceries:
 TODO Fix Conky          :fixes:
```

OR

```
 :groceries::      TODO Get milk                
 :fixes::          TODO Fix Conky
```

But just getting rid of the ugly file name would be great help
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Tags should be aligned by default.  The option `org-agenda-tags-column` can be used to configure the details of alignment.  That doesn't seem to be working for you, so please post a minimal example to the Org list that can be used to trigger the issue.

You can adjust the prefix by configuring the option `org-agenda-prefix-format`.  The default for the `todo` view is " %i %-12:c" (see that option's docstring for information about what those specs mean).  You can get the format you want by setting the value to " ".  For example with

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-prefix-format '(todo . " "))
```